# Add Checkbox in Treeview

Tags: apache-flex

I am Learning in flex 3.0.
I want to create sample application which display tree view.

How to Add Check box in flex's tree view control?

Help me....

Comment: If you're just learning, don't use Flex 3, it's already old and deprecated.  Flex 4.5 is the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that isn't what you are looking but maybe can help

http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a31/Flex-Checkbox-TreeItemRenderer.html